# Join thread in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Probably asked before, but after the serious searching I'm still not able to find a proper solution. Please consider something like this:

```
function compute() {
  asyncCall(args, function(err, result) {
  });
  /* 'join thread here' */
}
```

Even though `asyncCall` is asynchronous I'd like to use the `result` and return it from the function `compute` synchronously. `asyncCall` is a library call and I can't modify it in any way.

How to wait properly for the asynchronous result **without `setTimeout` and watching a conditional variable?** This is possible but suboptimal.

Comment: And what exactly do you want? Either you freeze the thread as Akash suggests, or the function ends before the result is returned. Returning a reference as dandavis suggests seems to be reasonable alternative. Maybe you could describe the expected behavior more?

Comment: The problem is this is a controller code (MVC). The data must be ready before I render the view so I must stop and wait for the data. As I'm not primarily JavaScript coder, I resist to believe that there is no nice solution better than `setTimeout` and wait.

Comment: When developing in JavaScript, you have to be in an event-oriented frame of mind. Everything is handled by events. When the data has loaded, send an event (callback, whatever) to the UI part of the code, which can update the interface. Before that, continue showing the old data in the interface, or show a loading screen, or whatever. But never wait for an asynchronous call to complete.

Comment: And what if you call `compute()` and the rendering code inside the asyncCall?

Comment: It's pretty hard to flip it that way. I only wanted to know, if there is some simple solution. I know, that it's not the JavaScript way. As dandavis pointed out there will be something like promisesA which finally sounds right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `await` syntax in browsers that is widely available.  Your options are generally limited to Callback patterns or Promises.

NodeJS follows a callback pattern for most async methods.

```
function someAsyncMethod(options, callback) {
  //callback = function(error, data)
  // when there is an error, it is the first parameter, otherwise use null
  doSomethingAsync(function(){
    callback(null, response);
  });
}

....
someAsyncMethod({...}, function(err, data) {
  if (err) return alert("OMG! FAilZ!");

  // use data
});
```

Another common implementation is promises, such as [jQuery's .ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method...

```
var px = $.ajax({...});
px.data(function(data, xhr, status){
  //runs when data returns.
});
px.fail(function(err,xhr, status){
  //runs when an error occurs
});
```

Promises are similar to events...

Of the two methods above, the callback syntax tends to be easier to implement and follow, but can lead to deeply nested callback trees, though you can use utility patterns, methods like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to overcome this.

Answer (score 3):

not sure how you can really use something that doesn't exist yet, but it's easy enough to return a slot where the result will be:

```
function compute() {
 var rez=[];
  asyncCall(args, function(err, result) {
    rez[0]=result;
    if(rez.onchange){ rez.onchange(result); }
  });
  /* 'join thread here' */
 return rez;
}
```

now, you can refer to the [0] property of the return, and once the callback comes in, compute()[0] will have the result. It will also fire an event handler you can attach to the returned array that will fire when the data updates inside the callback.

i would use something more formal like a promise or secondary callback, but that's me...

EDIT: how to integrate a callback upstream:

```
// sync (old and busted): 
function render(){
  var myView=compute();
  mainDiv.innerHTML=myView;
}

//async using my re-modified compute():
function render(){
  var that=compute();
  that.onchange=function(e){ mainDiv.innerHTML=e; }
}
```

see how making it wait only added a single wrapper in the render function?

Comment: This is completely wrong, isn't it? If I'm not mistaken function `compute` returns immediately.

Comment: compute does return right away, returning an array where the result of the callback will eventually find itself. It's impossible to do any better than that i'm afraid... Look into promisesA for a more proper method.

Comment: But that's not what I want. ...but link to promisesA seems interesting.

Comment: @martin: perhaps, but sadly that's as close as you're going to get. Don't try to delay a return using some while loop, eval, throw, or other hackery...

Comment: but imagine this is a controller code (in MVC), data must be ready before the view is rendered. How can I wait for the data then?

Comment: @martin: im afraid a re-factoring is likely in your future. you can move the code that renders the view into the callback of the compute(). let me show you how to use closure to make this as painless as possible, updating answer.

Comment: Oh, you're right... maybe it's an architectonic problem. Right, that finally seems like an answer ;-) Thank you.

Comment: @martin, substitute res.end(e) instead of the innerHTML=e, the principle is the same regardless.